# Highlight and fade out the border of a specific row in the datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I would like to "highlight and fade out the border of a specific row" when that row is updated in the datatable. Can you guys please help me to get the same.

Comment: What do you mean with 'datatable'? And do you have any code for us to work?

Comment: In component based MVC frameworks datatable is a UI component that dynamically renders a HTML table based on a collection

Comment: Do you have any source code?

Comment: $scope.editemployeeEvent = function(user)
    {
                   $http({method  : 'POST',url: '../editemployeeEvent.do',
                   params: {id:user.id,code:user.code,eventName:user.eventName,status:user.status},
                 }).then(function(response)
              {
                  $scope.dtInstance.rerender();
                  $scope.user=[];
              });
            
        
     };

Comment: Why dont you post the code in your question? This is a Q/A website and not a 'make my homework' website. You seem to put little to not effort in this question so don't expect us to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This will give idea.

After reading the table data, store the value in `tableData` before updating. After update again store the data 'freshData' then loop through both something like bubble sort. If `currentRowData` not equals to data from the `freshData.row` then high light the table row at that index.

```
var beforeUpdate = tableData;
var afterUpdate = tableUpdatedData;
for(){
  if(beforeUpdata.row.data != afterUpdate.data.row){
       // here high light using index value
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is necessary if hes using angular which has built in change detection.

Comment: you will have <td> tags. Just highlight the border-bottom